# dual boot fails after Windows 10 update

Tags: package-management

After a Windows 10 update my dual boot has been wiped. I used my USB with Ubuntu 18.10 to boot my computer, went to a live session, opened terminal and typed :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

The response was that there are no official repositories for Cosmic cuttlefish. Internet is connected as I can access items in firefox.

Is this problem related to Cosmic being replaced by Ubuntu version 19? I have seen similar issues trying to update other software. The problem is that I have a Ryzen 3 2200G cpu that only has Win10 drivers. AMD does not supply anything for any other Windows (including win7) and no Linux drivers of any sort. The only Linux I could use is Ubuntu 18.10: Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04 do not support my CPU and neither does 19.10. So I am being forced to "update" from Ubuntu 18:10 to what? I had expected this sort of bullying from microsoft, but from Ubuntu? I accept that I should not have bought an AMD cpu but its too late.

Is there any way to keep using cosmic cuttlefish or am I forced back to Windows?
Thank you for any help

Comment: Your 18.10 is EoL - end of life. Best to use only current versions. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases And 20.04.1 is now released and LTS or long term support which are released every 2 years and have 5 years of normal support. You may need some settings, but many with AMD Ryzen have installed Ubuntu. And Boot-Repair can only repair current versions. Many systems also need UEFI update & if SSD the SSD firmware updated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: @karel This sounds like a darn MS update bug. See my answer.

Comment: Oldfred - I appreciate my 18:10 is EoL but the Ryzen 3 2200G is a special cpu that AMD apparently only produced for Win10 (tho this was not stated anywhere in the documentation). I foolishly thought that any OS, especially a linux would run on it. I found that only Ubuntu 18:10 works reasonably well. To "update" as you suggest is NOT an option, it would be better to go back to windows.

Comment: I don't know of any reason that Ubuntu 20.04.1 wouldn't run on your CPU. Build yourself a Ubuntu Live USB and see if it boots.

Comment: hello heynnema, my cpu does not work with Ubuntu 18:4 or 19:4 - can you quote a source that says it will work with 20:4 or are you just saying that no cpu manufacturer would make a cpu that only runs Win10? Guess what AMD is that dumb and none of the "experts" writing gushing reviews on how great the Ryzen 3 2200G (or the ryzen 5 G) were aware it was a win10 only cpu. Including computer magazine writers - go figure?

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: At power up, if you boot directly into Windows, without seeing the GRUB menu, then the following may not apply. Different fix.

---

**Windows 10 Anniversary Update**, and the more recent **Windows 10 Creators Update**, have a really bad habit of wiping out Linux partitions on **MBR disks**. Microsoft has known about this bug for quite some time, but has chosen not to fix it. Sounds like you're a victim.

Recovery is possible, but it can be tricky.

Boot to a current Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Open `Software & Updates` and make sure that all of your software repositories (except proposed) are enabled.

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update           # update the software database
sudo apt-get install testdisk # install testdisk
man testdisk                  # read the manual
sudo testdisk                 # start testdisk
```

You can also get specific instructions here: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Help for photorec here: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

**Note**: after recovery, strongly consider changing your MBR formatted disk to GPT format, so future MS updates won't wipe it again.

Comment: I can boot into my boot usb of ubuntu 18:10 but cannot get updates as 18:10 is Eol. Catch 22?

Comment: @Peterk When you turn on your computer, does it boot directly into Windows? Can you get to the GRUB menu? Did you try my answer with your 18.10 USB?

Comment: @Peterk Try my procedure, but skip the first command, `sudo apt-get update`, and see if you can do the remaining commands, with your 18.10 USB. Otherwise, you'll need to create a newer USB.

Answer (score 0):

I created a boot usb of Boot-repair using Balena Etcher. Booting from this allowed me to use the standard repair (top offer on the startup window) which fixed my computer with some errors. Currently I am in my Ubuntu 18:10 and trying to see if there are any issues. So far all is good.